# monit with ssl (https)

Tags: debian, ssl, https, monit

I recently installed monit (on debian) and everything is working fine. Now I would like to enable ssl support. I did what I found in the documentation:

```
set httpd port 2812
  ssl enable
  pemfile /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
```

Now not only can I not reach the server through the web with https://myserver.com:2812, but the communication between the monit daemon and the monit command fails as well:

```
$# monit status
monit: Openssl read timeout error!
monit: error connecting to the monit daemon
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get it working? ;)

Comment: The problem is missing `allow user:pass` line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you did not generate a SSL certificate.
Here some pointers (i've done it on my Ubuntu).

Ensure `Openssl` is available on your system, if not `apt-get install openssl`

- Create folder `/var/certs`
- Navigate to this folder `cd /var/certs`
- create a file named `monit.cnf` and copy/paste the following into it, then save and close the file :

> ```
> #create RSA certs - Server
>    RANDFILE = ./openssl.rnd
>    [ req ]
>    default_bits = 2048
>    encrypt_key = yes
>    distinguished_name = req_dn
>    x509_extensions = cert_type
>    [ req_dn ]
>    countryName = Country Name (2 letter code)
>    countryName_default = MO
>    stateOrProvinceName    = Ile de France
>    stateOrProvinceName_default     = Monitoria
>    localityName                    = Paris
>    localityName_default            = Monittown
>    organizationName                = the_company
>    organizationName_default        = Monit Inc.
>    organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name
>    organizationalUnitName_default  = Dept. of Monitoring Technologies
>    commonName                      = Common Name (FQDN of your server)
>    commonName_default              = server.monit.mo
>    emailAddress                    = Email Address
>    emailAddress_default            = root@monit.mo
>    [ cert_type ]
>    nsCertType = server
> ```

- Then run (press `enter` each time you are prompted for infos) :

> openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -config ./monit.cnf -out
>   /var/certs/monit.pem -keyout /var/certs/monit.pem

- Set permissions : `chmod 700 /var/certs/monit.pem` (in my case `user:group` for pem file is `root:root`)

Set the following in your `monitrc` config file :

```
set httpd port 2812
   ssl enable
   pemfile /var/certs/monit.pem 
   allow user:pass
```

Restart `monit`

And then it works ! Now it's up to you to put your real infos in the `monit.cnf` file and run the `openssl` command again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I thought I could use the snakeoil certificate already present in the system which I already use for https. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: I'll upvote your answer as soon as I have some reputation ;)